# How to integrate AzSK in VSTS CI-Build

Tags: azure, security, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Am working on Secure DevOps Kit for Azure(AzSK) using VSTS CI&CD. For working AzSK in VSTS there were two tasks named "AzSK ARM Templete Checker" and "Secure DevOps Kit(AzSK) CICD Extensions for Azure" which are available from Market place. But, here am unable to access "Secure DevOps Kit(AzSK) CICD Extensions for Azure" task after adding both to my organisation. Is there any extension/install additional tasks to add them for accessing it?

[image]

[image]

Please suggest me to "How to add it to my CI-Build Definition"

Comment: What's that mean for "`here am unable to access "Secure DevOps Kit(AzSK) CICD Extensions for Azure" task` "?

Comment: I want to work with Secure DevOps Kit(AzSK) CICD Extensions for Azure task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the screenshot, you have installed the [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=azsdktm.AzSDK-task).

`Secure DevOps Kit(AzSK) CICD Extensions for Azure` is just the name of the extension. And the real task is **AzSK ARM Template Checker**.

So, you just need to add the **AzSK ARM Template Checker** task under test hub.

---

**UPDATE:**

Well, please note that another **AzSK_SVT** task (`AzSK Security Verification Tests`) is available in '**Release**' pipeline tasks only.

So to use it you need to create a release pipeline,... then add the AzSK_SVT task from Test category. Please see [Security Verification Tests (SVTs)](https://github.com/azsk/DevOpsKit-docs/blob/master/03-Security-In-CICD/Readme.md#security-verification-tests-svts-in-VSTS-pipeline) for details.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Andy. According to link(extension) which you are shared me is showing that "It consists of two tasks" in which one indicates ARM Templates and another indicates about the Applications. Here i want work with Applications not ARM Templates

Comment: @Mani Well, please note that another **AzSK_SVT** task (`AzSK Security Verification Tests`) is available in '**Release**' pipeline tasks only. So, to use it you need to create a release pipeline,... then add the AzSK_SVT task accordingly. See the updated answer...

Comment: sorry for late response.It's working fine for only few verification Tests only. I think, it is still in preview and Is there any chance to do AzSK_SVT task for Hosted Linux Agent

Comment: @Mani No chance to check that. Have you tried the task on Hosted Linux Agent, Does it not work?

Comment: Yeah @Andy. It is fine now

Comment: I got an error after adding this task, and the error is "No controls have been evaluated for ARM Template(s)". Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I am sorry to ask you a question not relative to your question.
(as it seems that your question is already anwered :)  )

I am using the same task in my relaese pipeline and I am trying to add custom checks because the default checks this task is doing is not good enough for me.
[This](https://github.com/azsk/DevOpsKit-docs/blob/master/07-Customizing-AzSK-for-your-Org/Readme.md#first-time-policy-setup---an-example) tutorial is really helpfull for trying to set things up, only I seem to just get to add custom baselinecontrols for a local module and not getting it to add it in the azure devops pipeline (more info about [my question](https://github.com/azsk/DevOpsKit-docs/issues/143) .
As you are also working on the same task I was hoping that you maybe could me help me figure it out.